# Prevent QGIS from loading WMS services when opening project

Tags: wms, map-service, qgis-2.18

I have a QGIS project with several hundred WMS and ArcGIS MapServer layers. Every time I open the project it starts loading them one by one, which my take quite a while.
[image]

Is there a way to prevent them from being loaded automatically?

I checked the Network Options menu, but besides setting connection timeouts, there is no option in regards to loading on startup.

Comment: The image you show in the question is a .sid image file not a WMS.  Several hundred layers in one project is a lot, what is the use case for having that many layers in one project?

Comment: @artwork21 The WMS behave the same as the .sid in the ArcGIS MapServer. They are 1*1Km aerial images (what else) of a larger area.

Answer (score 1):

I overcame a similar problem by creating a single polygon layer with 1 feature for each WMS extent.

I then populated a field in the attribute table with the URL for the associated WMS.

Then created an action to perform the get request when the user clicks on the feature they are interested in. That way only the relevant layers are loaded.

Comment: Sounds interesting.  Could you explain a bit more or include a screenshot of the action settings?

Comment: I've moved jobs so don't have access to that process anymore, so I can't take any screenshots or provide the code. It was quite easy though, check [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392518/qgis-action-loading-layer-in-gpkg) to help build the action and [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292475/adding-a-tiles-wms-openstreetmap-layer-with-python-in-qgis) to modify it to get it to work for WMS

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a look at that!