# Adding a Tiles/wms? (openStreetMap) layer with python in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3, pyqt

In my QGIS python plugin I want to add a background map (if the user haven't added one), hence I think I missing something in the url for the Tiles/wms service.. (the function returns `invalid layer`) Any suggestions?

```
    sources = [layer.source() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
    print(sources)
    source_found = False
    for source in sources:
        if 'xyz&url' in source:
            source_found = True
            print('found')
    if not source_found:
        print('adding')
        urlWithParams = 'type=xyz&url=http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=19&zmin=0&crs=EPSG3857'
        rlayer = QgsVectorLayer(urlWithParams, 'OpenStreetMap', 'wms')
        if rlayer.isValid():
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
        else:
            print('invalid layer')
```

Comment: What version of QGIS, are you using ?

Comment: QGIS3.. (I know how to add it with XYZ Tiles manually)

Comment: python to load xyz tiles https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klakar/QGIS_resources/master/collections/Geosupportsystem/python/qgis_basemaps.py > sources.append(["connections-xyz","OpenStreetMap Standard"

Comment: I know, it is a very nice script how to add the tiles to the browser, hence I would like to add it as a layer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tiles/WMS sources give you raster data. So, you have to use `QgsRasterLayer()` instead of `QgsVectorLayer()`.

Try in this way:

```
...
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'OpenStreetMap', 'wms') # EDIT THIS LINE

    if rlayer.isValid():
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
    else:
        print('invalid layer')
```

Comment: I knew it was an easy fix! Thx