# QGIS action loading layer in GPKG

Tags: qgis, vector-layer, actions

I have a kind of "vector catalog" in a GPKG. It's different rectangles with an attribute called "name of the layer".

In the same GPKG, I have all the different layers.

I'm trying to build an action in my vector catalog, so when I click on the rectangle I want, it loads the corresponding layer in QGIS.

I found some questions about loading raster, but I wasn't able to do something like that for vectors.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find below solution to do the job

The full code is the following

```py
from qgis.core import (
    QgsVectorLayer
)
# Change to your own GPKG path
path_to_gpkg = "path/to/your/own.gpkg"
# Replace [%layer_name%] with [%yourcolumnwithgpkglayername%]
gpkg_layer = path_to_gpkg + "|layername=[%layer_name%]"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(gpkg_layer, "[%layer_name%]", "ogr")
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Ive made a screen capture to illustrate the action

[image]

Comment: I have done what you said, but I have a warning: "2021-03-30T15:28:30     WARNING    Impossible de trouver la couche [%nom du layer%].()" which means QGIS can't find the layer... Are you sure of this line: gpkg_layer = path_to_gpkg + "|layername=[%layer_name%]" ? Cause I think it handle it as a string, not as an attribute!

Comment: I found the error... I can't use an attribute with "special" name (I had some space)!